# How to add updateend Event Listener to two objects?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

MY CODE (not the full script but necessary part for the question):

```
request_xhr (video_url, function (buffer)
{
  video.addEventListener('updateend', function ()
  {
    appending_new_sources();
  });
  video.appendBuffer(buffer);
});

request_xhr (audio_url, function (buffer)
{
  audio.appendBuffer(buffer);
});
```

I'm creating a video player with the Media Source Extension API. I have created two `source buffers` called `video` and `audio`. In the above small code I am sending two requests to a video and audio location, and appending the request in the `video` and `audio` which link to the video player. I have added an `Event Listner` of `updateend` to the `video` bufferer. The Event Listener opens the function `appending_new_sources()` once the `video` bufferer has been updated. I want to add an `updateend` on both of the bufferers together, the audio and the video. So the function `appending_new_sources()` should open when the video and audio has finished updating. I do not know how to do this. Please help.

Comment: Don't include line numbers in your code. (I've removed them for you. Twice so far.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a common handler and remember how many callbacks you've gotten; when you've gotten two, call `appending_new_sources`:

```
var callbacks = 0;
function handler() {
    if (++callbacks == 2) {
        appending_new_sources();
    }
}

request_xhr (video_url, function (buffer)
{
  video.addEventListener('updateend', handler);
  video.appendBuffer(buffer);
});

request_xhr (audio_url, function (buffer)
{
  audio.addEventListener('updateend', handler);
  audio.appendBuffer(buffer);
});
```

**But**, this is one of the many places promises are useful. If you give yourself a promise-enabled version of `request_xhr` (which might use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)), it can be cleaner:

```
// Promise-enabled request_xhr:
request_xhr_promise(url, function(buffer)
{
  // You'll need to check for the error condition and use reject if an error occurs
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      video.addEventListener('updateend', function() {
        resolve();
      });
      video.appendBuffer(buffer);
  });
});

// Using it for this:
Promise.all([
    request_xhr_promise(video_url),
    request_xhr_promise(audio_url),
])
.then(appending_new_sources)
.catch(function(err) {
    // Handle error
});
```